# Is it possible to print one and a half line(1.5x the normal height) in C#?

Tags: c#, console, lines

I know that you could print a line in C# using '\n' character. Is it possible to print out 1 and a half using C#.net special character. I'm doing this because I have this control in a client IOS application that would need to absorb a string with one and a half line thrown by a web service? thanks

Comment: Not to a console window or lineprinter. The question would only make sense in some formatting or markup system. Try HTML and CSS.

Comment: Im doing this because i have to pass a string value with half lines via web service so that a ios client app could consume it :) sorry failed to metion it.

Comment: @AllanChua, how the hell do you pass half-lines via a web-service....?!

Comment: @AllanChua: What *exactly* do you mean by a "half line"? Your question is really unclear at the moment. You should also clarify whether you *really* care about the console or not (it doesn't sound like it).

Comment: This sounds eerily like a new breed of "how do I make part of a string bold/italic?" question...

Comment: @AllanChua - You need to explain what a "half line" is exactly. How can you have a half of a line, if the length of the line, is determined by the number of characters you print to the line.  I still do not understand how you have half a vertical line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the console? No. Consoles don't support half lines. This isn't a C# limitation - it's a console limitation. A console is just a grid of characters, basically. Even colour is pretty hi-tech for consoles :)

(I'm assuming you're talking about a vertical line separation of 1.5 lines. If that's not what you mean, please clarify your question.)

Comment: Sorry if I've confused you, uhmmm the real question is: "Is there any special character dedicated for one and a half line thanks in advance.

Comment: @Allan Chua: No, there isn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think i have to quit for it.. thanks for the advice and another for the books you've wrote they help allot to me :)

Answer (score 8):

You could try this

[image]

Instead of this

[image]

lol Just kidding... :)

Maybe you could try HTML formatting ;)

Comment: Isn't that still `\n` but with shorter, er, legs? :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes first calculate one line how many character takes? (lest say forOneLine) and divide it 2
HalfLine= forOneLine/2 
so you already know length of one line(forOneLine), and now you know 0.5 (HalfLine), sum of them,
 total=HalfLine+forOneLine
according to lenght of sum (total) create an string array every index ' '

then with your output string just sum with total using + opearator.
thats it ;)

Comment: You seem to be confusing character width with line height.

Comment: Or if it is a Matter of Size he can use TextRender.MeasureString to get half of String Width or Height .

Answer (score 1):

No it's not because you never know how long a line is, it's just possible to start a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Half lines as in half of the string or display-wise as in half of the height of a line?? The latter is not possible, the first is obviously simply achieved using substring methods and length properties of the strings.

Comment: If there's way of achieving this I'll be very surprised mate, like Jon Skeet said you're hugely limited by what you can achieve interface ways on a console, and there isn't a character set to represent half characters either.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've edited the question, it entirely depends on how the client application is rendering the line and whether it pays attention to newline characters, and whether it word-wraps or not.  You need to specify *what* is actually rendering the line for this question to start making a bit more sense.